# Django. not able to access staticfiles in local development

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying serve static files in my local development (on same server I serve my site). I have run `./manage.py collectstatic` with the following configs:
**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
```

**template.html**

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'apis/icons/random-svgrepo-com.svg' %}" style="width: 50px;">
```

Now I have staticfiles folder in my **BASE_DIR** folder, but when I try to get an image, it doesn't appear to be working expected.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/apis/icons/random-svgrepo-com.svg`

[image: Working directory]

Please help. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you have not configured your static files and media files. Try configuring it as follows. In your settings.py ensure to include `STATICFILES_DIR, STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT` in your `settings.py` and then add the below lines below `STATIC_URL = 'static/'`:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles']
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/media'
```

By doing this you are telling django where to get your static files. now your have to add the link of the static files in your project `urls.py`. you will add that as below.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import 
static

urlpatterns = [
  .......
]
urlpatterns +=static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

One last thing that I assumed you had done is creating static folder in your project root and inside that static folder create media folder where all the images you want to load are. Now run `python manage.py` collectstatic